# Modeling question - flatten part of the cylinder

Tags: modeling

Got a question on modeling, would like to know if anyone can suggest a way on modeling this part of a chair? It is kind of flatten part of the cylinder. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might try to start with a subdivided cylinder that is bent the general direction this goes, and then try a booltool brush of a flat surface like an extruded cube to cut away that flat area, and then retopologize the result to fit your desired vertex arrangement.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know this Bool Tool addon before. Did some research in Google, found out this addon is included in v2.78

Enable this addon under File > User Preferences > Add-ons > Bool Tool
[image]

Select the rectangle first, then select the cylinder, use the Difference operation and got the below result.
[image]

Comment: You might look at the bevel modifier to get the slight rounded edge from the reference. I had mentioned retopology only in the case that you might want to actually have even distributed quads in your model -  but that is not always necessary, so is really just an after thought. The nice thing about the booltool brushes is that you can work with other modifiers liek Array to get really good effects quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The knife tool is a simple option. In the Gif I just filled with one big NGon. You could of course bridge the vertices and get neat geometry. The object is set to Auto-smooth with smooth shading.

[image: KZ key]

Answer (score 1):

You might try to start with a subdivided cylinder that is bent the general direction this goes, and then try a booltool brush of a flat surface like an extruded cube to cut away that flat area, and then retopologize the result to fit your desired vertex arrangement.

[image]

Comment: Copy your comment to answer, delete comment, and elaborate little more. How to use this AddOn? How to retopologize this particular example etc.

Comment: If you need to add an image to a comment then upload the image to somewhere like imgur and link to it. When you add an answer, all information should be in the answer itself, not split between answer and comment. In short, only add an answer if you intend it to be a full answer to the question.